# I wonder how do I get the 480p link from the video and put it in my player?

Tags: php

How do I get the 480p link from the video and put it in my player?

**My code player:**

```
        <span id='player-wrapper'></span>
        <script>
            var playerElement = document.getElementById("player-wrapper");

            var player = new Clappr.Player({
                source: '<?php 
$url = 'http://www.cdnkings.com/embed/'.$_GET['id'];
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('source');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {echo $tag->getAttribute('src') ;} 
?>',
                poster: '',
                mute: false,
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%'
            });

            player.attachTo(playerElement);
        </script>
```

**Code of the page I want to pick the link:**

```
<video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" onselectstart="return false" oncontextmenu="return false" controls preload="metadata" width="100%" height="100%" poster="http://www.cdnkings.com/contents/videos_screenshots/27000/27558/preview.jpg" data-setup='{"techOrder": ["html5"], "responsive": true, "nativeControlsForTouch": true, "customControlsOnMobile": true }'>
      <source src="http://www.cdnkings.com/get_file/1/900cbc98c9cbccc274440bf654ef77fc0a5c96cb2c/27000/27558/27558_240p.mp4/" type='video/mp4'

                        label='240p' res='240'/>

    <source src="http://www.cdnkings.com/get_file/1/7952c61a37ff1986b1f2de0d9670d8fbd9d8d128b2/27000/27558/27558_360p.mp4/" type='video/mp4'

                        label='360p' res='360'/>

    <source src="http://www.cdnkings.com/get_file/1/11383f582d325eebd0b7f4046e7a4cc7a1aaa62194/27000/27558/27558_480p.mp4/" type='video/mp4'

                        label='480p' res='480'/>

        </video>
```

Comment: Please explain in more detail about what you are trying to do and what you have done. You also should take a look at the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a conditional that checks the `res` attribute on the `source` tag as you're looping.

```
...
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    if($tag->getAttribute('res') == "480")
    {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
    }
}
...
```

Comment: @Julio Your issue with Clappr seems to come from your usage of '100%' for the height and width settings.  It only accepts fixed numbers, not strings/percentages.  If you remove those, it seems to work fine.  And if my answer resolved your issue, don't forget to mark it as accepted.